# cannot search in created PDF-File

Tags: pdftex

I write my bachelor thesis with texstudio under ubuntu 14.04. And I've noticed that I cannot search in the created file. I tried everywhere - evince, acroread, in texstudio integrated pdf-viewer.

I use for latex default settings only.

Do you have some advises for me?

---

Here can you see the "header" of the document:

```
\documentclass[draft=false
              ,paper=a4
              ,twoside=false
              ,fontsize=11pt
              ,listof=totoc             %schreibt toc,lot,lof in den Inhaltsverzeichnis
              ,headsepline
              ,BCOR10mm
              ,DIV11              
              ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} %             
%% see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-uselmfonts
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{amsfonts}  %import von sonderzeichen
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage[german,refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[ngerman,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[printer]{hawstyle}
\usepackage{lipsum} %% for sample text
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}





\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\usepackage{slashbox}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames,prologue]{pstricks}

%% define some colors
\colorlet{BackgroundColor}{gray!20}
\colorlet{KeywordColor}{blue}
\colorlet{CommentColor}{black!60}
%% for tables
\colorlet{HeadColor}{gray!60}
\colorlet{Color1}{blue!10}
\colorlet{Color2}{white}

%% configure colors
\HAWifprinter{
  \colorlet{BackgroundColor}{gray!20}
  \colorlet{KeywordColor}{black}
  \colorlet{CommentColor}{gray}
  % for tables
  \colorlet{HeadColor}{gray!60}
  \colorlet{Color1}{gray!40}
  \colorlet{Color2}{white}
}{}
\lstset{%
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  keywordstyle=\color{KeywordColor}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  commentstyle=\color{CommentColor},
  backgroundcolor=\color{BackgroundColor},
  captionpos=b,
  fontadjust=true
}
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, % used to enter latex code inside listings
        morekeywords={uint32_t, int32_t}
}
\ifpdfoutput{
  \hypersetup{bookmarksopen=false,bookmarksnumbered,linktocpage}
}{}

%% more fancy C++
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cxx}{C\raisebox{0.25ex}{{\scriptsize +\kern-0.25ex +}}}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

% unknown hyphenations
\hyphenation{}

%% recalculate text area
\typearea[current]{last}

\makeindex
\makenomenclature
%\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps complete the code to a small compilable example, upload your PDF file output somewhere and link here, so we could test and verify.

Comment: Check at the end of the log-file if you are using type1 font (.pfb) or bitmaps (.pk). Check what happens if you remove the (nonstandard) `hawstyle` package,

Comment: @Stafan Kottwitz: [link](http://www.fastshare.org/download/texprobe.ta..gz) contains sources and compiled pdf. 

@Ulrike Fischer: cannon delete the `hawstyle` package because it must be contained in the final version of document - this package make formate for the first 3 pages...

Comment: You should remove the style to *test* if it is responsable for the problem. Beside this: Why are you answering only to the second of my remarks?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry for this. its definetly .pfb (like here: `</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb>`)

Comment: Your example says something else, it shows lots of type3 (bitmap) fonts. Did you check all the fonts?

Comment: `.pk` is not there but many of `.600pk`. Is it this type?

Comment: These are bitmaps. Install the cm-super fonts. Or switch to \usepackage{lmodern}.

Comment: not relevant to the question, but `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically, so it's not necessary to do so separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found out in the comments the document used bitmaps fonts. This can be checked by looking at the list of fonts at the end of the log-file: `.pk` or `.600pk` or similar are bitmaps. If the bitmaps are the cm/ecfonts one can resolve the problem by installing the cm-super fonts or by switching to the lmodern fonts.